# Modify value for specified key in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of json objects (dictionaries) `ds_list`

```
ds_list = [ { "status": "NEW" },  { "status": "UP_TO_DATE" }]
```

I need to modify an attribute of each object.

So here is my solution:

```
if we_are_processing:
    result = list(map(lambda ds: ds.update({'status': 'PROCESSING'}) or ds, ds_list))

result = [ { "status": "PROCESSING" },  { "status": "PROCESSING" }]
```

It works, but I don't like it very much, in particular `update()` and `or ds`.

What is more pythonic (readable) way of implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pythonic way is to use `for` loop:

```
ds_list = [ { "status": "NEW" },  { "status": "UP_TO_DATE" }]

for item in ds_list:
    item['status'] = 'PENDING'

# [{'status': 'PENDING'}, {'status': 'PENDING'}]
```

Comment: I agree if they want to modify `ds_list` but in their example, they create a new list instead, although it's not so clear I admit

Comment: @Chris_Rands, You are right, it's ambiguous. I just read the line: "I need to modify an attribute of each object."

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thank you, guys. May be it's good that I left it ambiguous. Now I have solutions for both cases. Unfortunately I can accept only one.

Comment: @OlegPavliv, Use the one that works best for you. Don't worry, we won't be offended!